# iOS app not showing option for enabling / disabling notification

Tags: ios, iphone, notifications, local

I have an app that sends local notifications on respective events. One of my test user complains that he never sees the option to enable / disable Notifications for the app under Settings and thus the local notifications never work on his phone.

However, on my handset I see the option to enable / disable the notification option. And once enabled, the notifications work perfectly well.

Any help, as to why the test user does not see the option for enabling / disabling notifications on his handset?

The other options I see are available on his phone's "Settings" as well (namely: Access to Contacts, Microphone and Mobile Data).

Here are the two screenshots, without the notification option and with the notification option:
[image: Without Notification Option]
[image: With Notification Option]

Answer (score 0):

Happened once to me, here's what I did:

- Delete the app
- Delete all accounts or profiles linked with the app.
- Restart your phone.
- Re-install the app and your profiles should be installed automatically.
- Launch app.
- It should then appear in the notification center.

Comment: Sorry, that did not solve the issue. Moreover, since iOS 8 we can no longer manually delte the provisioning profiles linked to an app.